# Why doesn't u-Substitution work for $\int \ln({e^{6x-5}})\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I was trying to evaluate the indefinite integral $\int \ln({e^{6x-5}})\,dx$. I know that the correct way to solve it is to use the following property of logarithms: $$\ln{e^{f(x)}}=f(x)\ln{e}=f(x)$$
Using this property, the integral becomes $\int 6x-5\,dx$, and we can use the Reverse Power Rule to get $\color{red}{3x^2-5x+C}$ as the answer.

The above method was not my first attempt. I initially tried to solve it using u-substitution but got a different answer. I cannot find where the mistake occurs. Here was my first attempt:

$$u=6x-5 \\ du=6\,dx \Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{6}du=dx \\ \dfrac{1}{6}\int \ln{e^u}\,du=\dfrac{1}{6}\int u\,du \\ \dfrac{1}{6} \cdot \dfrac{1}{2}u^2+C \Rightarrow \color{red}{\dfrac{1}{12}(6x-5)^2+C}$$

I already checked that the two answers are not the same as their graphs are different. Where does the mistake occur?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I bet the graphs are exactly the same except one is shifted up or down from the other.  The only difference in the two answers is the $+C.$   The $C$'s aren't the same in both answers, but if you call one of them $D$, you can figure out how they're related.

See that

$$\frac{1}{12}(6x-5)^2+C = 3x^2 - 5x +\frac{25}{12} +C$$.

If $C$ is an arbitrary constant, then so is $\frac{25}{12}+C.$

Comment: You are right, the graphs are closely related: I will add a picture

Comment: B. Goddard's response shows that your two answers are the same

Comment: https://youtu.be/ZB0IFCmtphE is a nice video that shows another example of "different" integrals (that really only differ in the arbitrary constant).

Comment: @DreiCleaner   My favorite example is to integrate $\sin^2x +\cos^2x,$ blindly.